# How to access the Format function in a ComboBox derived class?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, string-formatting

I am writing a Combobox custom control and cannot use the `Format()` function. The editor marks the format line as an error.

```
Public Class TestCombo
    Inherits ComboBox
    Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawItem(ByVal e As DrawItemEventArgs)
        Dim MyStr = Format(5459.4, "##,##0.00")    ' The error is here.
    End Sub
End Class
```

After a little exploring, I found that Combobox uses ListControl as an event.
How can I tell the editor to address the function and not the event?

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, the ComboBox class has an [event called `Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.format) (which is inherited from `ListControl`). So, when you try to call the [`Format()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.format) inside `ComboBox`, the compiler thinks that you are trying to use the event [because it has the narrowest scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/references-to-declared-elements), hence, the error.

To get around this, you may explicitly call the module name (i.e., `Strings`) where the `Format()` function is declared:

```
Dim MyStr = Strings.Format(5459.4, "##,##0.00")
```

Alternatively, you may use [`String.Format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format) or [`ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring) *(which is the standard way in .NET)*:

```
Dim MyStr2 = String.Format("{0:##,##0.00}", 5459.4)

Dim MyStr3 = 5459.4.ToString("##,##0.00")
```